# 2hrs 15 mins layover time sufficient for Chicago?

Tags: short-connections, ord

I am travelling from India to USA. 1st stop is at Chicago and a layover for my next flight is 2hrs 5 mins. starting to end is single ticket and same airlines. is this time would be sufficient considering the immigration and customs check at Chicago as port of entry.

Answer (score 2):

- Handy connection guide https://www.flychicago.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/O%27Hare/MyFlight/TransferGuide.pdf
- You have a good chance of making it unless your inbound is significantly delayed, there are baggage problems or lines at immigration, customs, or security are unusually long.
- If you miss the connection, the airline will simply put you on the next available flight.